# How to convert UTF-8 to Windows-1252 in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, utf-8, character-encoding

I can not display a string in Windows-1252 after passing the encoding to UTF-8.

I am forced to convert to UTF-8 in init

```
feature('DefaultCharacterSet','UTF-8');

...
```

I would like to convert my string to Windows-1252 Character to display it:

```
disp('âêéôïèç');
```

I'm getting this result

```
�������
```

How can I do to get the correct following result?

```
'âêéôïèç'
```

Thanks!

Regards,

Comment: try `s = char([226 234 233 244 239 232 231]); disp(s)`? In general you can use `native2unicode` and `unicode2native` to convert between encodings..

Comment: it gives âêéôïèç. How did you do?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 :)

Comment: How can I get 226 234 233 244 239 232 231? I tried this but not work: uMsg = unicode2native(msg);
msg = char(uMsg);

Comment: sorry but what is `msg` in this case? what is the input, and what output are you looking for?

Comment: msg = 'âêéôïèç' output expected is 'âêéôïèç'

Comment: yes but the problem is that the way literal strings are interpreted is affected by the current character set. You'll have to reset to the default `feature('DefaultCharacterSet','Windows-1252')` then call `unicode2native('âêéôïèç', 'Windows-1252')` to get the above byte sequence... And yes I know, it feels broken to me too!

Comment: The point is if you know the Unicode codepoint of a character, you can get the encoding in the desired charset. For instance the french c-cedille [`ç`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e7/index.htm) which is `U+00E7`, is represented in UTF-8 as: `cellstr(dec2hex(unicode2native(char(hex2dec('00E7')), 'UTF-8')))` (which correctly returns `{'C3';'A7'}`). Replacing `UTF-8` with `Windows-1252` will give you `'E7'` (equal to `231` in decimal)

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer the original question, the following should work:

```
s = char([226 234 233 244 239 232 231]);
disp(s)
```